# PYTHON: operation on the dataframe index slice

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I have a dataframe with datetime indexes and some values:

| Index | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-29 13:26:55.740529776 | 0.023001 |
| 2021-07-29 13:26:55.762375355 | 0.021846 |
| 2021-07-29 13:26:55.805379868 | 0.043005 |
| 2021-07-29 13:26:55.819379330 | 0.014000 |
| 2021-07-29 13:26:55.849494696 | 0.041983 |
| ... | ... |

I would like to have a new column with the mean of values over the certain period of time (index slice), e.g. 1 second. Because the samples are not uniform in the time domain, I cannot use rolling window, which has fixed number of samples.

I tried the loop but it does not work:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
   df['mean'][i] = df['value'][df.index[i] - datetime.timedelta(seconds = 1): df.index[i]].mean()
```

Could you guide me how to make it in the most pythonic way?

Jarek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas rolling can take an interval as window e.g.

```
df['value'].rolling('1S').mean()
```